# How to copy the table elements to another in MVC razor view?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
  @model IEnumerable<WebApplication2.Models.FLA_TYPES>

  @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
  }

   <h2>Index</h2>

  <table class="table"  id="xyz">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NAME)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.rowguid)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NAMEA)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.rowguida)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

  @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NAME)          
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.rowguid)
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.NAMEA, new { htmlAttributes 
 = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>

        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.rowguida, new { htmlAttributes 
 = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </td>
        <td>           
            <button type="submit" 
 onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("show","FLA_TYPES",new{ 
 id=item.SUPERID})'" 
  >Show On UI</button>

        </td>
    </tr>
 }

 </table>
```

I am new to MVC and razor so I am trying to copy the value of `NAME` and `rowguid` into  `NAMEA` and `rowguida` all of them populated through a table.

On button click Event by calling the controller, but I need to do this using the jquery on button click event.

Can anybody help me out with this?
[image]

Comment: I dont understand: you want to copy values while clicking on "Show on UI" and after that you want to redirect the user to another page or what?

Comment: @RobertoConteRosito after clicking the button"Show On Ui" I want to copy the values on the same page itself.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution is simple:

```
$('table tr td button').click(function(e) {
   var $button = $(this);
   var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
   var $name = $row.find('td:eq(0)');
   var $rowGuid = $row.find('td:eq(1)');
   var name = $name.text(), rowGuid = $rowGuid.text();
   var $nameA = $row.find('td:eq(2) input');
   var $rowGuidA = $row.find('td:eq(3) input');
   $nameA.val(name);
   $rowGuidA.val(rowGuid);
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Provided cose is "verbose" to allow you to understand steps required to get your goal. 
I still not understand why you are adding "onClick" event on the same button. 
The code on top just copy values, nothing else.